# Where accessing swap space is handled in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, memory, swap

**I am working as a research assistant and this question is really vital for our group:**

We are looking for a way to inject delays when a process (i.e. a python program) is using swap space. For example, if in a normal way, it is swapping-in pages from swap space to main memory to work on it, we need to make a delay before that. (I know it doesn't make sense in the real world to make a delay in the kernel when accessing swap space or main memory, but by doing that we will be able to simulate something which is important for us to do so.)

What I did before:

I already tried adding a `printk` statement to the following sections in the kernel but none of them seem to be the exact location of handling `swap-in` and `swap-out` for a process.

1. In the `memory.c` file, in the function `do_swap_page()`. It didn't work always.
2. In the `memcontrol.c` file, in the function `mem_cgroup_swapin_charge_page`. It just works when the application is newly allocating the swap space. (And not whenever it is using the swap actually)
3. In the `swap_state.c` file, in the function `swapin_readahead()` and also in the function `swap_vma_readahead()`.

None of them works even when the process is using swap space.

Note 1: I am using the latest version of the kernel (6.0.9). But I don't think it will be different with different versions of the Linux kernel.

Note 2: I am measuring the amount of swap used with the command `free -m`. Also, more information is available in the `/proc/meminfo` file. So, I am sure that my process is using swap space, but I don't know how to catch it in the kernel source code.

It has been weeks that I am looking for an answer but no success. Any help is so appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try backtracing from the kernel hooks that respond to the `malloc()` system call.

Comment: Generally, what if you just added the delay to the storage device you reside the swap on?

Comment: That said, this definitely sounds like something you'd best ask on the kernel development mailing list.

Comment: @Shadur `malloc()` isn’t a system call.

Comment: Put swap on a usb2 hard drive?

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati it would be advisable to simply add sleep or waits in the kernel, so you’d have to add infrastructure in kernel to delay handling the system calls. In short this is a great deal of effort. I don’t see what value these waits gain you. Is it possible this is an XY problem? Where you are trying to solve problem Y by adding waits (X)?

Comment: @Shadur, I don't think it is related to the malloc, but thank you very much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, in our project, the swap space resides in a RamDisk, do you have an idea about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JamesRisner No, we are simulation something using this method. Other methods are not feasible, in the literature, 2-3 other papers have done something similar to it but not exactly the same.

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati so, then modify the Ramdisk code or if there's any hooks you can use, eBPF is your friend.

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati go with eBPF as Marcus suggests.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you. I will look at what is eBPF then hopefully I can do it.